# ElasticSearch JAVA API Multiple sub aggregation Sum

Tags: java, elasticsearch

I have a document "suppliers" for this document i jave three Fields (A, B and C) , So the case is i want a term aggregation for A after that a term sub aggregation for B and finaly a sum other sub Aggregation for C .

A = "TOTO" 
B="01"
C="122"

A="TOTO"
B="01"
C="10"

A="TOTO"
B="01"
C="10"

Result : A=TOTO B=01 C=142

Here the real case

```
SearchRequestBuilder requestBuilder = client.prepareSearch(ConfiguratorDao.DLPA_LAST_DAY)
                    .setTypes(IndexTypeEnum.SUPPLIER_WARNING.getValue()).setQuery(queryBuilder);

  MetricsAggregationBuilder aggregation1 =
                    AggregationBuilders
                            .sum("Sum_W_1ST_BO_WITH_DELAY")
                            .field(SupplierFieldEnum.W_1ST_BO_WITH_DELAY.getLabel());


 final TermsBuilder suppIdNumber = AggregationBuilders.terms("id_sup_number")
                    .field(SupplierFieldEnum.ID_SUP_NUMBER.getLabel());

            requestBuilder.addAggregation(suppIdNumber
                    .subAggregation(AggregationBuilders.terms("code_supplier_dlpa_site")
                            .field(SupplierFieldEnum.CODE_SUPPLIER.getLabel()).subAggregation(aggregation1)));
```

Response :

```
"aggregations": {
    "id_sup_number": {
      "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 265,
      "sum_other_doc_count": 99058,
      "buckets": [
        {
          "key": "095436",
          "doc_count": 16325,
          "code_supplier_dlpa_site": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": []
          }
        },
        {
          "key": "028390",
          "doc_count": 12303,
          "code_supplier_dlpa_site": {
            "doc_count_error_upper_bound": 0,
            "sum_other_doc_count": 0,
            "buckets": []
          }
        },
```

Comment: what is the error are you getting with your code. also whats the exact query it is firing in case it is error free compiled.

Comment: whats the type of 'requestBuilder'

Comment: i didn't have any error but all the buckets are empty